# Build one more model after dropping the features with importance

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, feature-selection

We build a Data Science model and watch feature importance. If we drop the features and build a new model , will there be any improvement in the accuracy?. I see only one advantage is that consumer of model can pass  only limited parameters to get the prediction. Are there any other advantages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!
Fewer parameters mean a faster learning and a faster prediction. Done correctly, it also means a smaller chance of overfitting your data.

Answer (score 0):

The non-relevant features act as a noise, thus it will reduce the accuracy of the model.

While training the model it makes the convergence towards global minima harder, as it minimizes a more complex function.

Comment: Thanks .. I dont see any improvement in accuracy . does it ?